# perform different splits based off different criteria to create a distinct output

Tags: python

When I execute the below python code I have written, (I am trying to create a user name based off three distinct scenarios (1.user enters First, middle, and last name, 2. user enters first and last name, 3. user enters only last name. I am attempting to create a username based off the first 4 characters of the last name+first initial (when provided)+middle initial(when provided). When I execute the below code, using the first+last name combination or just last name, I receive

> ```
> lastName = (listnames[2])
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

```
def entirename(fullName):
        lowername = str.lower(fullName)
        delimiter =' '
        listnames = (lowername.split(delimiter))
        lastName = (listnames[2])
        lname = lastName[0:4]
        fInit = listnames[0]
        fname = fInit[0]
        mInit = listnames [1]
        mname = mInit[0]
        username =lname+fname+mname
        return
def firstlast(fullName):
        lowername = str.lower(fullName)
        delimiter =' '
        listnames = (lowername.split(delimiter))
        lstName = (listnames[1])
        lname = lastName[0:4]
        fInit = listnames[0]
        fname = fInit[0]
        username = lname+fname
        return
def last(fullName):
        lowername = str.lower(fullName)
        delimiter =' '
        listnames = (lowername.split(delimiter))
        lstName2 = (listnames[0])
        lname = lstName2[0:4]
        username = lname
        return
def main():
        print "Hello! This program will contruct a new userid for you."
        print ""
        fullName = raw_input('Please enter your full name: ')
        while True:
            if fullName[2]:
                entirename(fullName)
                break
            elif fullname[1]:
                firstlast(fullName)
                break
            elif fullname[0]:
                last(fullName)
                break

main()
```

Comment: retagged to python as this isn't using python 3.x print & input.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could write something simpler like:

```
def get_id():
    print "Hello! This program will contruct a new userid for you.\n"
    name = raw_input('Please enter your full name: ').lower().split(' ')
    userid = name[-1][:4] # first 4 chars of last name
    if len(name) > 1:
        userid += name[0][0] # first char of opt first name
    if len(name) > 2:
        userid += name[1][0] # first char of opt middle name
    return userid

userid = get_id()
print 'userid:', userid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your main() is wrong. ... fullname[2] is the third character of the string... if I am not mistaken...? Since it's not split yet.

EDIT:

So split() it in main() and you should be good to go.

Also notable that you can't str.lower() a list. Which is what tipped me off.

RE-EDIT:

This should do the trick. Fully tested rewrite:

```
def main():
    print "Hello! This program will contruct a new userid for you.\n"
    fullstring = raw_input('Please enter your full name: ')
    fullName = fullstring.split(' ')
    lowerName = list()
    for each in fullName :
        lowerName.append(each.lower())
    lowerName.reverse()
    lastname = lowerName.pop(0)[0:4]
    lowerName.reverse()
    if lowerName : lastname += lowerName.pop(0)[0]
    if lowerName : lastname += lowerName.pop(0)[0]
    return lastname

main()
```

Comment: I still receive error: 
def main():
        print "Hello!This program will construct a userid."
        print ""
        fullName = raw_input('Please enter full name: ')
        while True:
            if fullName.split():
                entirename(fullName)
                break
            elif fullname.split():
                firstlast(fullName)
                break
            elif fullname.split():
                last(fullName)
                break  
main()